# Spring Data does not handle Pageable argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/findAnchorInfoByPage")
public void findAnchorInfoByPage(@PageableDefault(value = 50) Pageable page,HttpServletRequest request) {
    anchorInfoService.findByPage(page);}
```

this is my pom.xml fragment.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

applicationContext.xml fragment:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <ref bean="sortResolver"/>
        <ref bean="pageableResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="sortResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
<bean id="pageableResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
    <constructor-arg ref="sortResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration"/>
```

but Spring Data itself works fine, JPA repositories are working. But until now I had hand-written pagination in controllers. I have following error:
`org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface`

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have update spring version to 4.2.6.RELEASE and update spring-data-mongodb version to 1.9.1.RELEASE. It's work fine now.